# How to remove validation Rule from Ideal Forms jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, rules, idealforms

Trying to remove validation rule from Ideal Forms and cannot get rid of it!.
When value is less than 3 I am adding Rules to validate 4 extra fields but when I enter value more then 3 I want this validation be removed. I have been trying to add inside else statement but doesn't work. Please help

```
$('#previous_year').keyup("input", function() {
        var dInput = this.value;

        if(parseInt(dInput) < 3){
           $('form.idealforms').idealforms('addRules', {
            'postcode4': (parseInt(dInput) < 3) ? 'required' : '',
            'memo3': (parseInt(dInput) < 3) ? 'required' : '',
            'previous_year2': (parseInt(dInput) < 3) ? 'required' : '',
            'previous_month2': (parseInt(dInput) < 3) ? 'required' : ''
                    });
                    $('form.idealforms').idealforms('goToStep', 3);
            } else {

//remove rule here!

            } 
});
```

Had a look into documentation and I have got following updates, but this still acting wrong as if you have drop down and you select one option you are disabling element and if you select other option you are enabling it, its a direct loop

```
.idealforms('toggleFields', names)

Show or hide fields. When the fields are hidden they will be excluded from the validation.

names: A space separated string of name attributes.
Example:

$('form').idealforms('toggleFields', 'username password hobbies[]');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#employment_details').change(function() {
    if (this.value == 'Retired') {  
        $('form.idealforms').idealforms('toggleFields', 'company_name getemployed');
        $('form.idealforms').idealforms('goToStep', 5);
    }

    if (this.value == 'Employed') { 
        $('form.idealforms').idealforms('toggleFields', 'monthly_pension_amount pension_type getretired');
        $('form.idealforms').idealforms('goToStep', 5);
    }

    $('#employment_details').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```